# Creating a recursive function to cycle through lists that produce lists that produce lists... and so on

Tags: python, list, algorithm, recursion, data-structures

First off I'm using python.

I have a list of items called tier1 it looks like this.

```
tier1 = ['a1','a2,'a3',..,'an']
```

I have 2 functions called functionA and functionZ.

They both take a string as their argument and produce a list output like this. The lists must be produced during execution time and are not available from the start. Only tier1 is available.

listOutput = functionA(tier1[0]).

listOutput looks like this

```
listOutput = ['b1','b2,'b3',..,'bn']
```

The next time functionA is used on listOutput lets say item 'b1', it will produce

```
listOutput = functionA('b1')
```

```
output:
listOutput = ['bc1','bc2,'bc3',..,'bcn']
```

This time when functionA is used, on lets say 'bc1', it might come up empty, so functionZ is used on 'bc1' is used instead and the output is stored somewhere.

```
listOutput = functionA('bc1')
```

output

```
listOutput = []
```

So I use

```
listOutput = functionZ('bc1')
```

output

```
listOutput = ['series1','series2','series3',....,'seriesn']
```

Now I have to go back and try bc2, until bcn doing the same logic. Once that's done, I will use functionA on 'b2'. and so on.

The depth of each item is variable.

It looks something like this

[image]

As long as listOutput is not empty, functionA must be used on the listOutput items or tier1 items until it comes up empty. Then functionZ must be used on whichever item in the list on which functionA comes up empty.

After tier1, listOutput will also always be a list, which must also be cycled through one by one and the same logic must be used.

I am trying to make a recursive function based on this but I'm stuck.

So far I have,

```
def recursivefunction (idnum): #idnum will be one of the list items from tier1 or the listOutputs produced

    listOutput = functionA(idnum)

    if not listOutput:
        return functionZ(idnum)
    else:
        return recursivefunction(listOutput)
```

But my functions return lists, how do I get them to go deeper into each list until functionZ is used and once it's used to move on to the next item in the list.

Do I need to create a new kind of data structure?
I have no idea where to start, should I be looking to create some kind of class with linked lists?

Comment: It's really not clear to me what you are trying to do. It would really help if you provided a [mcve] with inputs and expected outputs

Comment: Are you saying that `functionA` takes a single string as an argument `tier1[0]` and produces a list of strings as the output? I.e. if you apply `functionA` to all of `tier1` (which is a list of strings), you end up with a list of lists of strings?

Comment: each one will produce its own list of strings yes

Comment: For which case will `functionA()` return empty string.

Comment: i tried doing this using for loops already by the way, but I can't account for every case once it keeps going deeper and deeper.

Comment: there's no way to know, the only way is to test, but when it returns an empty list, functionZ() must be used instead on the same string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I understand your problem:

- there is an input list `tier1`, which is a list of strings
- there are two functions, A and Z

  - A, when applied to a string, returns a list of strings
  - Z, when applied to a string, returns some value (type is unclear, assume list of string as well)
- the algorithm:

  - for each element of `tier1`, apply A to the element
  - if the result is an empty list, apply Z to the element instead, no further processing
  - otherwise, if the result is not empty, apply the algorithm on the list

So, in Python:

```
from random import randint
# since you haven't shared what A and Z do, 
# I'm just having them do random stuff that matches your description


def function_a(s):
    # giving it a 75% chance to be empty
    if randint(1, 4) != 1:
        return []
    else:
        # otherwise between 1 and 4 random strings from some selection
        return [['a', 'b', 'c'][randint(0, 2)] for _ in range(randint(1,4))]
        # in the real case, I'm sure the result depends on `s` but it doesn't matter


def function_z(s):
    # otherwise between 0 and 4 random strings from some selection
    return [['x', 'y', 'z'][randint(0, 2)] for _ in range(randint(0,4))]


def solution(xs):
    # this is really the answer to your question:
    rs = []
    for x in xs:
        # first compute A of x
        r = function_a(x)
        # if that's the empty list
        if not r:
            # then we want Z of x instead
            r = function_z(x)
        else:
            # otherwise, it's the same algorithm applied to all of r
            r = solution(r)
        # whatever the result, append it to rs
        rs.append(r)
    return rs


tier1 = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4']

print(solution(tier1))
```

Note that `function_a` and `function_z` are just functions generating random results with the types of results you specified. You didn't share what the logic of A and Z really is, so it's hard to verify if the results are what you want.

However, the function `solution` does exactly what you say it should - if I understand you somewhat complicated explanation of it correctly.

Given that the solution to your question is basically this:

```
def solution(xs):
    rs = []
    for x in xs:
        r = function_a(x)
        if not r:
            r = function_z(x)
        else:
            r = solution(r)
        rs.append(r)
    return rs
```

Which can even be rewritten to:

```
def solution_brief(xs):
    return [function_z(r) if not r else solution(r) for r in [function_a(x) for x in xs]]
```

You should reexamine your problem description. The key with programming is understanding the problem and breaking it down to its essential steps. Once you've done that, code is quick to follow. Whether you prefer the first or second solution probable depends on experience and possibly on tiny performance differences.

By the way, any solution written as a recursive function, can also be written purely iterative - that's often preferable from a memory and performance perspective, but recursive functions can have the advantage of being very clean and simple and therefore easier to maintain.

Putting my coding where my mouth is, here's an iterative solution of the same problem, just for fun (not optimal by any means):

```
def solution_iterative(xs):
    if not xs:
        return xs
    rs = xs.copy()
    stack_rs = [rs]
    stack_is = [0]
    while stack_rs:
        r = function_a(stack_rs[-1][stack_is[-1]])
        if not r:
            stack_rs[-1][stack_is[-1]] = function_z(stack_rs[-1][stack_is[-1]])
            stack_is[-1] += 1
        else:
            stack_rs[-1][stack_is[-1]] = r
            stack_rs.append(r)
            stack_is.append(0)
        while stack_is and stack_is[-1] >= len(stack_rs[-1]):
            stack_is.pop()
            stack_rs.pop()
            if stack_is:
                stack_is[-1] += 1
    return rs
```

Comment: your answer is really good, I learnt programming myself so I had no idea where to start in solving this. your advice is really good. thanks!

Comment: Happy to help - the best way to understand a recursive function, is to use a good debugger and step through all the code. Keep in mind that every time the recursive function calls itself, it basically creates a new copy of the function and its local variables somewhere in memory and it just starts with the parameters that are passed in. Most new programmers have trouble because they either don't return values correctly, or they assume the recursive call is just like a loop, operating on the same data over and over.

Comment: This is just a recommendation, my opinion, but I really like PyCharm. The community edition is free and good enough for almost any project, certainly for starters. There are plenty tutorials online to learn how to work with it. It may seem a bit intimidating at first, but if you learn to work with it, you'll know how to use tools that will also serve you if you ever become a professional or a seasoned amateur.

Comment: this might be a stupid question, but is it possible to not have the for loop within the function? because the format in which my functionA and functionZ return the lists to me are like this ```testlist = {'cat':[{'id':'b1','year':1995,....}, {'id':'....}...]}```. so i have to do this ```'testlist['cat']'``` and when i cycle within the list within ```'cat'``` i have to do ```item['id']```

Comment: What you're saying is you're not manipulating lists, but dictionaries - I'm sure an equally simple solution is available, but you'd need to share a bit more information about your problem. In general, it's best (on StackOverflow or when programming in general) to think about the simplest possible situation that still has the actual problem and answer it in that context. You haven't given me enough information for me to know what the problem is, so I cannot answer your question. I don't think "removing the for loop" is the solution though.

Comment: Hey @Grismar, I posted a new question and updated it with the new data structure and some new requirements, if you have the time please take a look, could really use your help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62046118/recursive-function-that-also-handles-exceptions-to-cycle-through-a-list-of-dic